# Gmail doesn't recognize email addresses at fully qualified domains

Tags: gmail, domain

Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDNs) may end with a final dot (e.g. `www.example.com.`).

I understand the final dot indicates a FULL domain, and name matching shouldn't be tried on assumed domains.  *(ie. do not try to match www.example.com.edu, even if sent from inside a .edu site that is configured this way)*

But if I try to send to a valid email address via Gmail that ends with a final dot, I get the error:

> The address "user@example.com." in the "To" field was not recognized. Please make sure that all addresses are properly formed.

Is Gmail correct in considering **company-dot-com-dot** improperly formed?  Is this a Gmail error, or is there a reason that email addresses shouldn't use FQDNs that end with a final dot?

Comment: Just curious.. Are you really trying to send an email to an email that ends with  a dot or you just accidentally left the dot in the end and got the error message?!

Comment: I found this issue with a simple copy-paste (the address was at the end of a sentence, so I copy-pasted the final dot by accident).   But I'm definitely curious if this is a gmail bug, or if they know something about email addresses that I don't.

Comment: I'm guessing they never had an actual case that the email was ending with a dot, so instead of having that feature they decided to throw an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It would appear](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/3f61e5d2-d1d2-4927-b12d-aa00a4085bd4) that Gmail and now Outlook are going against some interpretation of the RFCs.